# How to set PlotRange->All for data with uncertainties and prevent cropping of error bars?

Tags: plotting

Mathematica 12 introduces built-in plotting support for data with errorbars.

The following example looks good with the default settings:

```
ListPlot[Table[Around[i, 5], {i, 10}]]
```

[image: Correct plot range]

However, when I set `PlotRange->All`, the error bars get cropped:

```
ListPlot[Table[Around[i, 5], {i, 10}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Cropped error bars]

Here is an example, where default PlotRange crops error bars:

```
ListPlot[{Table[{i, Around[1/i, {-10, 10}]}, {i, -5.5, 5.5, 1.0}], 
          Table[{i, 3 i}, {i, 0.5, 5.5, 1.0}]}]
```

[image: Cropped error bars]

and adding `PlotRange->All` does not help either:

```
ListPlot[{Table[{i, Around[1/i, {-10, 10}]}, {i, -5.5, 5.5, 1.0}], 
          Table[{i, 3 i}, {i, 0.5, 5.5, 1.0}]}, 
         PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Cropped error bars]

Is there a universal option to get the full PlotRange for any data with error bars?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** This issue is fixed in version 13.0. Using `PlotRange -> All` prevents cropping of the error bars:

```
Row[{ListPlot[Table[Around[i, 5], {i, 10}], 
    ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> All],
  ListPlot[{Table[{i, Around[1/i, {-10, 10}]}, {i, -5.5, 5.5, 1.0}], 
      Table[{i, 3 i}, {i, 0.5, 5.5, 1.0}]}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> All]}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

A work-around: use `Show` with the option `PlotRange -> All`:

```
Show[ListPlot[Table[Around[i, 5], {i, 10}]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListPlot[{Table[{i, Around[1/i, {-10, 10}]}, {i, -5.5, 5.5, 1.0}], 
      Table[{i, 3 i}, {i, 0.5, 5.5, 1.0}]}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

An alternative work-around is to use explicit range for the vertical axis:

```
tbl = Table[Around[i, 5], {i, 10}];
yrange = MinMax[#["Interval"]& /@ tbl];
ListPlot[tbl, PlotRange -> {Automatic, yrange}]
```

[image]

For the second example:

```
tbl2 = {Table[{i, Around[1/i, {-10, 10}]}, {i, -5.5, 5.5, 1.0}], 
        Table[{i, 3 i}, {i, 0.5, 5.5, 1.0}]};
yrange2 = MinMax @ Flatten[tbl2[[All, All, 2]] /. a_Around :> MinMax[ a["Interval"]]];
ListPlot[tbl2, PlotRange -> {Automatic, yrange2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems that if one replaces the PlotRange option in the resulting graphics expression by PlotRange->All, all works out. The resulting Graphics from

```
ListPlot[Table[Around[i, 5], {i, 10}],PlotRange -> All]
```

(if one inspects it via InputForm) has an explicit set of plot ranges

```
PlotRange -> {{0.8125000000000003, 10.}, {0, 10.}}
```

But replacing that with PlotRange->All explicitly the wished-for graphic is obtained

```
ListPlot[Table[Around[i, 5], {i, 10}],
    PlotRange -> All] /. (PlotRange -> _) :> (PlotRange -> All)
```

This seems to be a bug.  For example if one evaluates a simple plot

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All] // InputForm
```

the PlotRange is

```
PlotRange -> {All, All}
```

and has not been transformed into an explicit numerical PlotRange.
I will send in a bug report and see what the response is.

Comment: In your final example of a simple plot, try usual procedure: `PlotRange[Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]]` and you will get explicit numerical intervals (without taking `PlotRangePadding` into account). And I think your variant with further replacing `PlotRange` is essentially what `Show` does. Nevertheless, very useful observations, +1.

Comment: Hi Alx, Cases[Plot[x,{x,0,5},PlotRange->All],z:(PlotRange->_):>z,Infinity] gives  {PlotRange->{All,All}} and not an explicit numerical interval.  Perhaps I misunderstood the first part of your comment though.  BTW I checked with WRI bugs and submitted this -- it is likely related to a known bug that they are aware of.

Comment: I only meant that ususal way to know plotrange is `PlotRange[<your Plot command here>]` or undocumented `get2DPlotRange` from `Charting` context.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read your comment carefully enough!  My appologies Alx.